# Patterns with special characters in Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LikeOperator.LikeString does not work

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, design-patterns

I have tried to use the LikeOperator.LikeString functionality for pattern matching as shown below:

```
    // Usage: bool matchValue = LikeOperator.LikeString(string, pattern, CompareMethod);
    bool match = LikeOperator.LikeString("*test*/fe_quet", "(*)test(*)/*", Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Text);
```

The above should return true as per the documentation, but it simply returns false. I tried to escape the (*) with the brackets, but it does not seem to work in that way. Could anyone please help me to define the pattern string with the special characters?

Thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I did not understand, such a case is not mentioned anywhere here: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) Could you please type the complete pattern string for me? Thanks a lot

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Unfortunately, prepending the tilde will not escape the astericks in the pattern string. It did not work :(

Comment: Actually I need to escape the asterisks in the pattern string, since they have a different meaning ("Zero or more characters match") in the pattern strings.

Comment: I can help with a regex if you want a regex solution. However, these wildcards are quite OK in this scenario once you use a character set `[...]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I had some problems with the regular expressions in the past while using for the same purpose, hence I decided to go with this functionality!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Like Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) (which you provided):

> To match the special characters left bracket ([), question mark (?), number sign (#), and asterisk (*), enclose them in brackets.

Therefore you need to wrap your asterisks in [] instead of ():

```
bool match = LikeOperator.LikeString("*test*/fe_quet", "[*]test[*]/[*]", Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Text);
```

You'd probably be better off using Regex instead of the VB namespace.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, That's it! Thank's a lot, so mistake for not reading it properly. Thanks again "A Friend" :)

Comment: I am new to the regular expression language, so that I though to keep it simple, better to use the LikeOperator. Do you see any major issue in using this instead of Regex?

Comment: There's nothing *wrong* with it, but Microsoft do advise against using this function directly, even in VB [(source)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.likeoperator.likestring(v=vs.110).aspx). The VB `Like` operator calls this.